# On mouse hover change image for 8 sec pause and change to another one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want a way to change the PNG to animated GIFs on mouse hover as follow :

on moues hover on the PNG image => 8 seconds load first animation. Pause for 4 seconds and load the next animation pause for 4 seconds and load the final.

my code as follow

```
<img id="mylogo" src="images/unicorn-logo-white.png"/>

<script>
function chnageGif(){
 
    $('#mylogo').attr("src", "images/Looped Pooping Rainbow CU Logo + Text.gif");
}

    $(function() {
        $("#mylogo").hover(
            function() {
              setTimeout(chnageGif, 8000);
                $(this).attr("src", "images/Loop Dance CU Logo + Text.gif");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/unicorn-logo-white.png");
            }                         
        );                  
    });
```

now I can only change the image one time after 8 seconds, I need to make one more change for 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the setTimeOut function and it works for me , but sometime the last one interrupt the second one. This my solution to my problem , if any one has a better way to do the same goal please replay , Thank you

```
function lastGif(){
  $('#mylogo').attr("src", "GIF-1");
}
function chnageGif(){
    $('#mylogo').attr("src", "GIF-2");
}
    $(function() {
        $("#mylogo").hover(
            function() {
              setTimeout(chnageGif, 8000);
              setTimeout(lastGif, 16000);
                $(this).attr("src", "GIF-3");
                clearTimeout(chnageGif);
              clearTimeout(lastGif);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "PNG");
            }                         
        );                  
    });
```